# Delphi - How to close a form from WITHIN a TFrame on that form?

Tags: forms, delphi, tframe

In Delphi 2010, I am creating a form, and then creating a TFrame, assigning TFrame.Parent to the form, and then showing the form MODALLY.  Works fine...  The frame has a DBNavigator, a field DBFields,etc.  When the user clicks on Post/Save, I want to automatically close the Form.  I have tried a few things, such as Close, Action = caFree, (DBNav.parent.parent) as TForm.Free, etc and nothing seems to work.  How do I - from within a TFrame, close the Form?

Code to create this thing is...

```
 // Create the Window
    ThisWin := TEmptyFrameWin.Create(nil);

  // Create the Frame for the Window
  ThisFrame := TFrameUsage.Create(Application);

  ThisFrame.Parent := ThisWin;

  // Load the data
  ThisFrame.tUsage.Open;
  ThisFrame.tUsage.FindKey([StrToInt(ID)]);
  ThisFrame.LoadDateFields;

  ThisWin.Caption := 'Change Appointment Information';
  // Only show the POST button    
  ThisFrame.UsageNav.VisibleButtons := [sbPost];

  try
    ThisWin.ShowModal;
  finally
    ThisWin.Free;
  end;
```

Thanks,

GS

Comment: Use `Release` instead of `Free` for subclasses of TForm.

Comment: There's no need for that here, @Marcus. `Release` is for when the form is being destroyed from within a message handler of the form or one of its controls. From the code shown here, it's impossible for the form to be processing any message at the time `Free` gets called, so everything is fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From a method within the frame class, you can reach the host form by calling `GetParentForm`. So, the following would meet your needs:

```
GetParentForm(Self).Close;
```

Comment: +1 Didn't know this function. Implemented it several times myself for different projects. Thanks!

Comment: This does what the OP asked, but if I was code-reviewing the OP's code I'd say "that's terrible".  Make the frame have a `OnRequestClose` property/event (really a callback) and have the owner form decide whether to close, and what logic it wants to do before closing, and even whether to hook up the callback.